# Count each time a string appears in a longer string, Python

Tags: string, for-loop, python-3.x

I'd like to count if a string can be found within a longer string.

For example, if i have the string: "Heyheyheyhey".
I'd like to check how many times the part "ey" is in the string, and get the count 4.
Lets say that i have this string in a list aswell.

I tried this, but it works just if the part appears one time in the string.

```
For word in list:
   count = 0
   If 'ey' in word:
       count +=1
```

I thought exchanging the if to a while would work, but obviously not. Any tips?

this is all in PYTHON 3.x.

Comment: I'd suggest tagging this question with the relevant language for some more views.

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

With the string method [count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> 'Heyheyheyhey'.count('ey')
4
```

With a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall(r'ey', 'Heyheyheyhey'))
4
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to match multiple things, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> s='Hey hi how'
>>> sum(1 for i in range(0,len(s)) if s[i] in 'eyio')
4
```

Or a regex:

```
>>> len(re.findall(r'e|y|i|o', s))
4
```

Comment: Can one or both of these be used to count the number of vokals at the same time? That would be quite nice for me. 

like:
"Heyhi".count('e','y','i') should return 3 or something